# Include whole page in variable (PHP)

Tags: php, events, live

I'm trying to create a page where I can force updates to the client without a page refresh. So I Googled and Googled and Googled and ended up here: http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/pushing-updates-to-the-web-page-with-html5-server-sent-events/ - **it was *almost* a success**!

I managed to adapt the code enough so that I can include a page instead of using the example rand() and thus, whenever I modify that page and upload it to my FTP, the page updates. ***However, I cannot figure out how to output a whole file*** - only the first line of that file (maindiv.php). I've come to understand that it has to do with using "file_get_contents". How can I achieve a full output of "maindiv.php" here?

My pages codes are:

**index.php:**

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#serverData
{
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    top:0;
    left:0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:green;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="serverData">Here is where the server sent data will appear



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
//check for browser support
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
    //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
    var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");
    //detect message receipt
    eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data;
    };
}
else {
    document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML="Whoops! Your browser doesn't receive server-sent events.";
}
</script>
</html>
```

**send_sse.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    $maindiv = file_get_contents("maindiv.php"); //this does not read more than one line
    echo "data: $maindiv\n\n";
    ob_flush();
?>
```

**maindiv.php:**

```
<div style="background:blue; display:inline-block; width:300px; height:500px;color:white;">Line 1<br>
Line 2<br>
Line 3<br>
Line 4<br>
Line 5<br>
Line 6<br>
Line 7<br>

</div>
```

Comment: I think: `file_get_html` instead of contents but actually, it should read everything out with file_get_contents too. Did you allowed `fopen` in php.ini?

Comment: It's probably because the messages are separated by double-newline.  It's not meant to send whole files.  I'd suggest just pushing a message that triggers JS to request the new file using XHR.

Comment: @Doomenik tried file_get_html instead, but then it returned the fallback only ("Here is where the server sent data will appear") from the div with ID "serverData". I'm not finding anything that's only called `fopen` but my server has `allow_url_fopen` set to `On`

@JosiahKeller I have no idea what that is.

Comment: @JosiahKeller if I remove the new lines, the fallback shows (i.e. this stops working)

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is it's expecting newlines to separate the messages, so it's not a good choice for sending a whole file

Comment: So, I might have to find a whole new solution to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence Well, like I said, you could keep using SSE, but just send a message that tells the browser "update now!"  Then, when your JS receives that message, use Ajax to load the actual file.  That would be a more robust solution.

Comment: @JosiahKeller oh, I see. Thank you!